# How to change admin.initializeApp when deploying different environments

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am using Firebase Functions. I have 2 environments: one for dev and other for staging.

My question is how can I change `admin.initializeApp` config when deploying to each environment because the `databaseURL` is changing:

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: [...],
  databaseURL: "someurl"
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this just like you are using the Firebase Admin SDK in a regular node.js app.  [The setup instructions are here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start).  There are also instructions in the Firebase console when you go to download the project's service account credentials.

When you download the service account key file, you can put it in your `functions` directory so it can be loaded with require() and passed to `initializeApp`.

Comment: is any way to do some auto or throw cli to change all this setting its on index  and on firebase functions...

Comment: @Doug how to know which credential file to pick based on the project environment set in CLI using firebase use alias-name?